# Reinitializing a variable/record in PL/SQL during a loop

Tags: loops, plsql, io

In order to create a PL/SQL parser for an ETL process, in which data is mainly positional-encoded, I have the need to read a file line-by-line and add records to an in-memory (package-scoped) table into the current record or into a new record.

Let me briefly explain the scenario and the grammar rules: I need to parse banking alignment messages, which have a public standard format (can't find English documentation, only [this](https://www.buonconsiglio.com/servizi/ici/help/SIA_RI_ICI_ALL.pdf) and other Italian documents, while this should be an EU-wide standard). Anyway here are some rules explained:

- Each record is 120 characters long in the file
- Every file begins with an "AL" (ALignment) record
- Every file ends with en "EF" (End of File) record
- Each alignment message begins with a "12" record and ends with a "70" record
- Depending on the type of the "12" record, the message can be made of different combinations of other records, like "30" and "40", "50", "45", "50" and "45" "50"

Example (structured):

```
AL record
    12 record
        45 record
    70 record
    12 record
        45 record
        50 record
    70 record
EF record
```

I already declared a `MESSAGE` PL/SQL table of `CHAR(120)`, which shall encapsulate records between 12 and 70 (included), those will be processed in a later stage. Now I have a looping problem that I could easily solve in Java.

How can I reinitialize a variable in PL/SQL? Here is a pseudo-Java example of what I need to do

```
String line;
List<String> alignment_message;
List<AlignmentMessage> table;
while (line = readline()) {
    if (line.substring(1,2)=="12") //Begin of message 
        alignment_message = new MESSAGE(); //******HOW DO I DO THIS????
    alignment_message.add(line); //Don't care about NPE ;-)

    if (line.substring(1,2)=="70") //End of message
        table.add(alignment_message);
}
```

I have currently declared, in my PL/SQL procedure, a variable `msg` of type `MESSAGE`. If I do an `INSERT` into this variable, and then I `INSERT` this variable into a table that contains a column of type `MESSAGE` (and a couple of other columns I use for pre-processing), how can I perform new `INSERT`s into a **fresh** new msg variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare
  type message_t is table of char(120);
  v_message message_t := message_t('12 record', /* start */
                                   '40 record',
                                   '70 record', /* end */
                                   '12 record', /* start */
                                   '50 record',
                                   '51 record',
                                   '70 record'  /* end */
                                   );
  v_almessage message_t := message_t();
  v_i number := v_message.first;
begin
  while v_i <= v_message.last loop
    if v_message(v_i) = '12 record' then /* start of a block */
      dbms_output.put_line('start of a block');

      loop
        v_i := v_i + 1;

        if v_message(v_i) = '70 record' then /* end of a block */
          dbms_output.put_line('end of a block');

          /* Do whatever processing you need to do. I just print collected
          messages. */
          for j in v_almessage.first .. v_almessage.last loop
            dbms_output.put_line('aligment message: ' || v_almessage(j)); 
          end loop;

          /* Reset collected messages. */
          v_almessage := message_t();

          exit;
        end if;

        /* Collect block's aligment messages. */
        v_almessage.extend(1);
        v_almessage(v_almessage.last) := v_message(v_i);
      end loop;

    end if;

    v_i := v_i + 1;
  end loop;

end;
/
```

Prints:

```
start of a block
end of a block
aligment message: 40 record
start of a block
end of a block
aligment message: 50 record
aligment message: 51 record
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've declared `MESSAGE` as `TABLE OF CHAR(120)`, `TABLE OF CHAR(120) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER` or `VARRAY(...) OF CHAR(120)`, then you can do

```
msg.DELETE;
```

The [DELETE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#CJAFGFIG) methods on nested tables, index-by tables and varrays delete all elements from them.

When you `INSERT` `msg` into a table, Oracle appears to store a copy of it, rather than a reference to it.  Deleting all of the elements from `msg` won't cause data in your table to suddenly disappear.

Alternatively, if `MESSAGE` is a `TABLE OF CHAR(120)` or a `VARRAY(...) OF CHAR(120)`, you can call the `MESSAGE()` constructor, i.e.

```
msg := MESSAGE();
```